# css - Change active nav pills color Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, colors, navbar

I'd change the color of my active nav pills, i tried all way but i haven't do it. This code change only pills color(text color not change) when mouse is on the pills or it is clicking on theym, but not when they are active. Please help me

```css
.nav-pills>li>a.active,
.nav-pills>li>a:hover,
.nav-pills>li>a:focus {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="C:\Users\Fabry\Desktop\scuola\html\Immagini\Commercial Services\CS.ico" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> Commercial Services
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills nav-fill">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="false">Servizi</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="false">Partners</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="false">Prenota</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="false">Contattaci</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    background-color: deepskyblue!important;
    color: white!important;
```

use important for overriding your class

Comment: you must use `!important` carefully, it may override already used styles

Answer (score 1):

you can try this also:

```
ul{
  list-style-type:none;
}

li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  width:50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover{
  color:white;
}

li:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
  background:blue;
  text-color:white;
  width:70px;
  height:30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter bot the back-ground and the color this will do that(for bootstrap4)

```
.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .nav-link.active:hover,.nav-pills .nav-link.active:focus{
    background-color:deepskyblue;
    color:white;
    font-weight:550;

    }
```